# Ruby cannot find model without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got error: `Couldn't find Doctor without an ID` with information: `app/controllers/doctors_controller.rb:37:in`show51'` Here is the code, first line in show51 in controller is line 37:
controller/doctors_controller:

```
# GET /doctors/1
  # GET /doctors/1.json
  def show51
      @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:id])
      session[:current_doctor_id2] = @doctor.id

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @doctor }
    end
  end
```

doctors/views/show51:

```
  <div id="container">
  <center>
    <p>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
      <%= Doctor.find(session[:current_doctor_id2]).name %>
    </p>
  </center>
  </div>
```

Help me please solve this problem :)

Also doctors/index51.html.erb:

```
  <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
  <div id="container">
  <center>
    <h1>Lekarze przyjmujący:</h1>
<p>
Lista lekarzy przyjmujących w przychodni w porządku alfabetycznym   
</br>
Proszę o wybranie lekarza do którego wizyta ma zostać utworzona:"
</p>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Imie lekarza</th>
      <th>Nazwisko lekarza</th>
      <th>Specjalizacja</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @doctors.each do |doctor| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= doctor.firstname %></td>
        <td><%= doctor.lastname %></td>
        <td><%= doctor.specialize %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Szukaj terminu', show51_doctors_path %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

    <%= link_to 'Strona główna', welcome_index_path %>

  </center>
  </div>
```

Comment: `params[:id]` is coming as nil. Show us the view where you have the link to `show51`

Comment: doctors/index51.html.erb :
<td><%= link_to 'Look for schedule', show51_doctors_path %></td>

Comment: or your session[:current_doctor_id2] is nil

Comment: I am new in Ruby and I don't know how to solve this problem ;(

Comment: post the `doctors/index51.html.erb` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `doctors/index51.html.erb`:-

```
<td><%= link_to 'Szukaj terminu', show51_doctor_path(doctor) %></td>
```

Change the routes as:-

```
resources :doctors do
 collection do 
  get 'index 51'
 end
 member do
  get 'show51' 
 end 
end
```

Comment: the same unfortunately:(

Comment: I just want to display choosen doctor's data in show51 :)

Comment: post the routes for doctors_controller

Comment: resources :doctors do
    collection do
      get 'index51'
   get 'show51'
    end
  end

Comment: Solved, I had also change link to with show51_doctor_path, not show51_doctors_path :) Thank you :) I am really grateful:)

Answer (score 0):

Create a route:
get 'doctors/show51/:id', to: 'doctors#show51', as: show51_doctors_path

In the controller:

```
 def show51
      @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:id])
      session[:current_doctor_id2] = @doctor.id

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @doctor }
    end
  end
```

In the show:

```
 <div id="container">
  <center>
    <p>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
      <%= @doctor.name %> # You already have doctor assigned.
    </p>
  </center>
  </div>
```

In the index:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Szukaj terminu', show51_doctors_path(doctor) %></td>
```